# CakePHP get id value from input select

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have the`Celebrant` and`Celebration` models where a`Celebrant` has N`Celebration`. I am populating an input select in view of Celebration add that lists all registered Celebrant. Until then all right, the problem is that when you make the form submission the value of the select is coming as the number of select the viewing position, and I would like to come Celebrant ID.

Here's what I did:

CelebrationsController

```
$this->set('celebrants', $this->Celebration->Celebrant->find('list'));
```

view/Celebrations/add

```
echo $this->Form->input('celebrant_id', array('type' => 'select', 'label'=>'Celebrante', 'options' => $celebrants, 'empty' => __( 'Selecione um Celebrante' )));
```

model/Celebrant

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Celebration' => array(
        'className'    => 'Celebration',
        'foreignKey'    => 'celebrant_id'
     )
);
```

model/Celebration

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Celebrant' => array(
        'className'    => 'Celebrant',
        'foreignKey'    => 'celebrant_id'
     )
);
```

Comment: What does your save logic look like? So far, everything looks allright. Small tip: try to follow naming conventions for variables. If you'd name your list of celebrants `$celebrants`, the select will automatically display it, since it matches the expected name for `celebrant_id`. That way you don't have to set the `'options' => $select` bit in your options array at all.

Comment: thanks for the reply, as modified to select for $celebrants but still remains the same. Forgot to post before but the error I get is this:

`Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add     or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('sao_pedro'.'celebrations', CONSTRAINT 'fk_celebrations_celebrants1' FOREIGN KEY ('celebrant_id') REFERENCES 'celebrants' ('id') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I just fooling myself, the problem is only in the error:

`Error: SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint Violation: 1452 Can not add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('sao_pedro' 'celebrations' CONSTRAINT 'fk_celebrations_celebrants1' FOREIGN KEY ('celebrant_id') REFERENCES 'celebrants' (. 'id') ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

Celebrant ID is coming right, only the error persists, but in phpmyadmin I add a Celebration smoothly.

Comment: That is a database design problem and not so much a CakePHP problem. The record cannot be saved because of a contstraint on your database table for celebrants. What does your table look like (and most importantly, what constrains are set?).

Comment: I created the database with the MysqlWorkBench follows the pastebin of the generated code: 

[SQL][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/e9KPY4Z0

But that's normal functioning manually adding the database.